# How to get rid of col-md-* padding when nested in another row, without affecting the entire grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, haml

I got to modify a page written using HAML+SASS+BOOTSTRAP. The HAML file looks like this:

```
.row
  .col-md-6
    .panel.panel-default.panel-dashboard
      .row
        .col-md-6
          .panel-heading
            Title 1
          .panel-body
            Content 1
          .panel-bottom
            Link 1
        .col-md-6
          .panel-heading
            Title 2
          .panel-body
            Content 2
          .panel-bottom
            Link 2
  .col-md-6
    .panel.panel-default.panel-dashboard
      .row
        .col-md-6
          .panel-heading
            Title 3
          .panel-body
            Content 3
          .panel_bottom
            Link 3
        .col-md-6
          .panel-heading
            Title 4
          .panel-body
            Content 4
          .panel-bottom
            Link 4
```

The output have to be a row with two panels and in each panel with two columns.

```
     _________   _________
    |____|____| |____|____|
    |____|____| |____|____|
    |____|____| |____|____|
```

Unfortunately I get a padding between the columns inside panels, marked below with |x|:

```
     _________   _________
    |___|x|___| |___|x|___|
    |___|x|___| |___|x|___|
    |___|x|___| |___|x|___|
```

How can I get rid of this padding, without affecting the paddings in the entire scaffolding, given that the entire page has more similar consecutive rows, and some with colspanned elements.

Comment: A col is automaticaly creating a padding left and right. Add a class and delete this padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give something like this:

```
  .col-md-6
    .panel.panel-default.panel-dashboard
      .row.no-margin-cols
        .col-md-6
          .panel-heading
            Title 3
          .panel-body
            Content 3
          .panel_bottom
            Link 3
        .col-md-6
          .panel-heading
            Title 4
          .panel-body
            Content 4
          .panel-bottom
            Link 4
```

And SCSS as:

```
.no-margin-cols {
  *[class*="col-md-"] {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Does this work for you?

#### Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvpQeN

Answer (score 0):

```
.row
  .col-md-6 .padding0
    .panel.panel-default.panel-dashboard
      .row
        .col-md-6
          .panel-heading
            Title 1
          .panel-body
            Content 1
          .panel-bottom
            Link 1
        .col-md-6
          .panel-heading
            Title 2
          .panel-body
            Content 2
          .panel-bottom
            Link 2
  .col-md-6 .padding0
    .panel.panel-default.panel-dashboard
      .row
        .col-md-6
          .panel-heading
            Title 3
          .panel-body
            Content 3
          .panel_bottom
            Link 3
        .col-md-6
          .panel-heading
            Title 4
          .panel-body
            Content 4
          .panel-bottom
            Link 4
```

Add a css class to parent col-md*. here i have added .padding0
and Write css for padding0 class

```
.padding0{
padding-left:0 !important;
padding-right:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, vaasudev!  I try to avoid using "!important" and I need to keep a padding between the panels.